# Roslyn Region Trivia

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

How do I create a RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax?

Below is as close as I have gotten and it fails. The third parameter is defined as a "name" but there is not a type for that. I have tried literal, identifier and several others kinds of tokens but they all complain about the Kind. And is there a correct way to parse one so I don't have to do the "Replace"?

`trivia` is an existing C# SyntaxTrivia and I am creating a VB RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax:

```
Dim node As RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax =
                SyntaxFactory.RegionDirectiveTrivia
                              (SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.HashToken),
                               SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.RegionKeyword),
                               SyntaxFactory.Token
                                             (SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken, 
                                              trivia.ToString.Replace("#region ", "")
                                             )
                              )
```

Comment: According to [SyntaxFactory.RegionDirectiveTrivia Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualbasic.syntaxfactory.regiondirectivetrivia?view=roslyn-dotnet), each of the three parameters is a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxToken. Is your VS's Intellisense not working? Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Use the [source](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic/Generated/Syntax.xml.Main.Generated.vb#43629)! It indicates that it, specifically, wants a `StringLiteralToken`.

Comment: Yes Intellisense works but just there are many SyntaxToken kinds. The answer I was looking for is "StringLiteralToken." thanks. The other part of the question is how do you pick out the parts of one, I don't see anything I can cast a SyntaxTravia to that allows me to get at the parts specifically the StringLiteralToken.

Comment: With StringLiteralToken I get the same Message = "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: kind"

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know how the `SyntaxTree` is build for some specific `SyntaxNode` like the `Region` in this case. Here is what you can do:

Be sure you've installed the [.NET Compiler Platform SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK). This adds the [Syntax Visualizer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Syntax-Visualizer) to Visual Studio. It allows you to inspect the SyntaxTree of your source code.

Go to View->Other Windows->Syntax Visualizer or search for it in the Quick Launch bar to show the following panel:

[image: Syntax Visualizer]

Simply place the cursor on the code what you want to inspect. The Syntax Visualizer will jump to the specific node in the tree. If you click on the Region's name, you can see that the node is created with 3 specific tokens: `HashToken`, `RegionKeyWord` and a `StringLiteralToken`. The following code will create the same `RegionDirectiveTrivia`:

```
Dim regionDirectiveTriviaSyntax =
    SyntaxFactory.RegionDirectiveTrivia(
        SyntaxFactory.Token( SyntaxKind.HashToken),
        SyntaxFactory.Token( SyntaxKind.RegionKeyword ) , 
        SyntaxFactory.StringLiteralToken( "SomeRegionName" , "SomeRegionName") )
```